# Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear')

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer, require

First time using PHPMailer, and can't seem to get passed this require error .. I installed composer did the require PHPMailer/PHPMailer and tried changing the paths .. but still can't pass this error message:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '../PHPMailerAutoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in
>   /home/hiinfo53/public_html/grandbluehawaii.com/cgifile/contact_phpmailer.php
>   on line 15

```
<?php
/**
 * This example shows how to handle a simple contact form.
 */

echo getcwd();
$msg = '';
//Don't run this unless we're handling a form submission
if (array_key_exists('email', $_POST)) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');


   require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP - requires a local mail server
    //Faster and safer than using mail()
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'usm1260.sgded.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    //Use a fixed address in your own domain as the from address
    //**DO NOT** use the submitter's address here as it will be forgery
    //and will cause your messages to fail SPF checks
    $mail->setFrom('contact@grandbluehawaii.com', 'First Last');
    //Send the message to yourself, or whoever should receive contact for submissions
    $mail->addAddress('gail@hiinfo.com', 'Grand Blue Hawaii');
    //Put the submitter's address in a reply-to header
    //This will fail if the address provided is invalid,
    //in which case we should ignore the whole request
    if ($mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name'])) {
        $mail->Subject = 'A user has contacted you from grandbluehawaii.com';
        //Keep it simple - don't use HTML
        $mail->isHTML(false);
        //Build a simple message body
        $mail->Body = <<<EOT
"Aloha,\n\n"
"A user visiting grandbluehawaii.com has sent you a message".\n\n"
"Please make sure any Reply-To's this email is directed to user's email address".\n\n"
Email: {$_POST['email']}
Name: {$_POST['name']}
Message: {$_POST['message']}
EOT;
        //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            //The reason for failing to send will be in $mail->ErrorInfo
            //but you shouldn't display errors to users - process the error, log it on your server.
            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Message sent! Mahalo for contacting Grand Blue Hawaii.';
        }
    } else {
        $msg = 'Invalid email address, message ignored.';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Contact us</h1>
<?php if (!empty($msg)) {
    echo "<h2>$msg</h2>";
} ?>
<form method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"></label><br>
    <label for="email">Email address: <input type="email" name="email" id="email"></label><br>
    <label for="message">Message: <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="8" cols="20"></textarea></label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';` this path needs review. You need to do this based on the location of the files in the project.

Comment: @Scuzzy I tried altering path to reach appropriate directory (e.g. ../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/) but still get error .. I also can't locate PHPMailerAutoload.php

Comment: @Scuzzy I'm following this example, pretty exactly https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps

Comment: @Scuzzy this exact file correct? PHPMailerAutoload.php

Comment: can you actually find that file on your computer or project files? because that is the name the script is looking for. Except to say your script wants `PHPMailerAutoload.php` in the parent folder relative to itself.

Comment: @Scuzzy it's only reference in site is (sorry for format, it's search results) D:\Profile Content\gmatsushima\Websites\staging.grandbluehawaii.com\grandbluehawaii2017_staging\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\UPGRADING.md:
   14  
   15  ```php
   16: require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   17  ```
   18

Comment: try `require '../PHPMailer.php';` because that is the name of the file at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/src

Comment: @Scuzzy still receive same fatal error :(

Comment: If your PHP file is `/home/hiinfo53/public_html/grandbluehawaii.com/cgifile/contact_phpmailer.php`, then what is the **exact path** to `PHPMailerAutoload.php`?

Comment: @Phil it's root/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src (then there's a PHPMailer.php) but I'm unable to find the exact file of 'PHPMailerAutoload.php') .. another similar file is 'root/vendor/autoload.php'

Comment: If the file is not there, you shouldn't be surprised that it cannot be found. Looks like you're using Composer so you should only need to include `vendor/autoload.php`. What is the **absolute path on your server** to `vendor/autoload.php`?

Comment: @Phil with include('vendor/autoload.php'); I now receive the following error: Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/hiinfo53/public_html/grandbluehawaii.com/cgifile/contact_phpmailer.php on line 18

Comment: @Phil absolute path to server is staging.grandbluehawaii.com\grandbluehawaii2017\vendor\autoload.php

Comment: That is a URL, not a path. An absolute path is `/home/hiinfo53/public_html/grandbluehawaii.com/cgifile/conta‌​ct_phpmailer.php` but anyway, it seems you haven't installed PHPMailer via composer on your remote server. You should also use `require_once` instead of `include`

Comment: @Phil to install on remote server, is that something I'd do via wamp vs composer require phpmailer/phpmailer in command line? .. and noted on other corrections .. thanks, very new to this

Comment: Typically, if you don't have access to a remote shell, you would install everything locally and upload it all. Just make sure that you run `composer install` locally. Or maybe you just need to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I changed require_once to  require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php'; and am getting new error of Fatal error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/hiinfo53/public_html/grandbluehawaii.com/contact_phpmailer.php on line 21 .. hopefully getting warmer?

Answer (score 4):

You could have saved yourself a lot of pain by simply reading [the readme](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/README.md), which tells you how to load PHPMailer - which has changed with PHPMailer 6.0. `PHPMailerAutoload.php` does not exist any more. There is info about upgrading form older versions in [the upgrading guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md), but since this is a new project, you should never have got to this point, so I suspect you got started by using an obsolete script from elsewhere. Bad idea.

Install PHPMailer using composer:

```
composer require phpmailer/phpmailer
```

In your script, import the class into your namespace, load composer's autoloader, create a PHPMailer instance, and it will autoload the right classes automatically:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
```

That's all there is to it. If you're using SMTP, you'll need to `use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP` as well. When you're using composer, you should almost never have to even look at what is in `vendor/`.

If you don't want to or cannot run composer on your server, run it locally, and upload the vendor folder along with the rest of your code.

If you don't want to use composer, you can load the classes in `src/` manually.

All of this is covered in the readme.

Comment: agreed, although I will say going off of github example and then realizing helpful details in UPGRADING.md for a first time phpmailer user is confusing. i tried reinstalling phpmailer/phpmailer and did the rest of steps you suggested (thanks btw) .. and still receiving the following error: Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/hiinfo53/public_html/grandbluehawaii.com/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear')

Comment: in case this helps anyone - this 'use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;' got rid of any phpmailer errors for me .. still not receiving emails though, separate issue. closing this topic

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have a composer (like me), here is another solution:

```
require '../PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
require '../PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
```

Also add in all the new objects the fully-qualified name of the main PHPMailer class.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Comment: It is true that Readme.md is not clear. In my case i thought it had to be really installed. But it doesn't.